# Clearing cmd.exe memory or cache

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

The main question is how do I clear the command prompts memory or cache.

I ran this on cmd.exe

```
svn info <URL>
```

Which prompted me a for a username and password which I entered.

I then logged off and logged back in immediately and I entered that same command and I wasn't asked for a username and password. I want to clear this to test something without restarting my server!

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't asking how to clear subversion's cache? The command prompt didn't cache anything.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that is a good point, I might be asking that. I just assumed it was cmd that stored the username/password. Let me try.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are right, just deleted the Subversion/auth file. Is it worth adding and answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's subversion that's caching, not the command line. Just remove subversion's auth file.

Comment: Thank you David that worked. For windows users check `AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth` for Linux I guess its `~/svn/auth`